# why python gevent is slower than serial ?

Tags: python, gevent, urlopen

i am using [gevent](http://www.gevent.org/) to preform concurrent download.
based on [this](https://bitbucket.org/denis/gevent/src/tip/examples/concurrent_download.py#cl-4) example this is the code:

```
import gevent
from gevent import monkey

urls = ['https://www.djangoproject.com/','http://www.nytimes.com/','http://www.microsoft.com']
monkey.patch_all()

import urllib2
from datetime import datetime

def print_head(url):
    print ('Starting %s' % url)
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()   
    print ('%s: %s bytes: %r' % (url, len(data), data[:50]))

startTime = datetime.now()
jobs = [gevent.spawn(print_head, url) for url in urls]
gevent.joinall(jobs)
totalTime = datetime.now() - startTime
print "Total time: %s" % totalTime
```

my problem is that the above code takes much longer than the serial version and in most cases it is timed out. here is the serial version which is much faster:

```
import urllib2
from datetime import datetime

urls = ['https://www.djangoproject.com/','http://www.nytimes.com/','http://www.microsoft.com']

def print_head(url):
    print ('Starting %s' % url)
    data = urllib2.urlopen(url).read()
    print ('%s: %s bytes: %r' % (url, len(data), data[:50]))

startTime = datetime.now()    
for url in urls:
    try:
        print_head(url)
    except:
        print 'ops EXCEPTION :('

totalTime = datetime.now() - startTime
print "Total time: %s" % totalTime
```

Comment: There is something with www.microsoft.com, my results for your code are inconsistent. Sometimes `gevent` faster, sometimes `urllib`. And most time consumed by downloading microsoft.com page. Try it with list of another urls.

Comment: I'm getting random timeouts on microsoft.com and nytimes.com ... but only with the gevent version ... Strange ...

Comment: Disabling money patching "solved" the problem, If I use either ``patch_socket()``, ``patch_dns()``, or ``patch_httplib()`` it's unreliable & slow. If I disable all monkey patching it's twice as fast (~1.5s vs ~3s the sequential script takes) ... Don't ask me for an explanation :-/

Comment: @Carpetsmoker,There are too little urls. Response time of sites dependent on many factors. Try this list http://pastebin.com/3739te6J of urls. And if you'll run OP's tests few times, you'll see that microsoft will get timeouts not only with gevent.

Comment: using the url list that @reclosedev provided i get 'NotImplementedError: inet_ntop() is not available on this platform'

Comment: @yossi, I wass getting this error long time ago. Try to remove google.com, it's related to IPv6. There is some solution for this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok
the problem was an old gevent package.
i just uninstalled the old one and installed the new one from [here](http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/detail?name=gevent-1.0b1.win32-py2.7.msi&can=2&q=) as @reclosedev pointed out.
and it is now working fine.

Comment: I'm running on FreeBSD and got the same problem. gevent 0.13.6 with Python 2.7.2

Comment: Try updated package from official site http://code.google.com/p/gevent/downloads/list

Comment: @reclosedev 0.13.6 is the *latest* stable version so there's nothing to update. 1.0 is in early beta and I hope you did not suggest working with beta...

Comment: @PiotrDobrogost, there are some problems with 0.13.6 on Win32 (e.g. IPv6 support) and 1.0b1 solves them. It's up to others what to use.

Comment: I had the same problem with Ubuntu 12.04 and Gevent 0.13.8. Upgrading to Gevent 1.0rc2 fixed it.